# create jtable from database using codes and displaying database table records in it

Tags: java, database, netbeans, jtable

Yow, I am trying to add a jTable in my jFrame and I wanna display records from my database table to the jTable.

I was able to create a jTable(I put the code in the constructor) and manually inputted in the code the values to be displayed. It worked. But then when I try to call a method that retrieves data from the database, and try to display them inside the jtable. It gives me an error "NullPointerException".

**CODE in my constructor that creates the table:**

```
    String[] columnname = {"Subject Code", "Prelim", "Midterm", "SemiFinal", "Finals"};
    setTable();
    Object[][] data = {};

    gradetable = new JTable(data, columnname){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int columns){
            return false;
        }

        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer r, int data, int columns){
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(r, data, columns);

            if (data % 2 == 0){
                c.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            }
            else{
                c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }

            if (isCellSelected(data, columns)){
                c.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            }
            return c;
        }
    };
    gradetable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension (400, 150));
    gradetable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    jsp = new JScrollPane(gradetable);
```

**Method I used to retrieve the data from the database and add them to the table:**

```
private void setTable(){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)gradetable.getModel();
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");            
        Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/grading","root","");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();      
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN grade ON student.idnumber = grade.idnumber WHERE student.idnumber = '2010-00125'";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        model.setRowCount(0);
        while (rs.next()){

            //this.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            //this.setCourse(rs.getString("course"));
            //this.setYear(rs.getString("year"));

            String d1, d2, d4, d3, d5;

            d1 = rs.getString("subjectcode");
            d2 = rs.getString("prelim");
            d3 = rs.getString("midterm");
            d4 = rs.getString("semifinal");
            d5 = rs.getString("finals");

            model.addRow(new Object[]{d1,d2,d3,d4,d5});
        }           
        rs.close();
        con.close();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Always post **full** StackTraces if you have any.

Comment: Show the code where you calling `setTable()` method

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the `NPE` is that you are calling `setTable` which tries to get the `JTable` model here:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)gradetable.getModel();
```

This is *before* you have actually instantiated `gradetable`, so the `NPE` is thrown.

Aside from this, you need to use `DefaultTableModel` when setting the model of the `JTable`, otherwise you will get a `ClassCastException` on this line.